# writing multiple text files from lists in while loop python: only one file obtained

Tags: python-3.x

I have three lists with directors, movies, and actors.  A director has one or many movies and a movie has one or many actors.  This is indicated in the list with separator '#' as follows:

```
directors[director1,director2]
movies[director1movie1,director1movie2,#,director2movie1,...] 
actors[movie1actor1,movie1actorN,#,movie2actor1,movie2actorN,...]
```

I am trying to write text files in python that displays the content as follows for each movie:

```
John_Wick

Willem_Dafoe
Keanu_Reeves
Bridget_Moynahan
John_Leguizamo
Dean_Winters
Alfie_Allen
Adrianne_Palicki
Michael_Nyqvist
Ian_McShane

Director: David_Leitch_(actor)
Director: Chad_Stahelski
```

My code achieves this, but it only writes one text file for one movie, although the code output shows it iterates through all items in all three lists and there is two movies in the lists:

Code:

def write_to_TxtFile(self,directorsL,moviesL,actorsL):
        countMovieL = -1
        countActor = -1

```
    for director in directorsL:
        countMovieL += 1
        print('------------------------ ')
        print(director)
        while moviesL[countMovieL] != '#' and countMovieL != len(moviesL):
            print('------------------------ ' + str(countMovieL))
            print(moviesL[countMovieL])
            if not(os.path.exists(moviesL[countMovieL] + '.txt')):
                with open('{}.txt'.format(moviesL[countMovieL]),'a')as file:
                    file.write(moviesL[countMovieL] + '\n\n')
                    countActor += 1
                    while actorsL[countActor] != '#' and countActor != len(actorsL):
                        print(actorsL[countActor])
                        file.write(actorsL[countActor] + '\n')
                        countActor += 1
                    file.write('\nDirector: ' + director + '\n')
                    file.close()
            else:
                file = open(moviesL[countMovieL] + '.txt','a')
                file.write('Director: ' + director+ '\n')
                file.close()

            countMovieL += 1
            if not(file.closed):
                file.close()
```

**Code output:**
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wps5i.png)

**Problem:**
The John Wick text file is always written, but the John Wick chapter 2 text file is never written.  This is irrespective of the order of movies in the list (John Wick chapter 2 before or after John Wick). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the code is correct, but I did not account that the movie name may contain one of these characters: [\,/,:,*,?,",<,>,|] and these may not appear in the name of a text file.

Removed all of above characters from string and all files were created:

```
for character in notAllowed:
    if character in nameX:
        nameX = nameX.replace(character,'')
```